# Lambda expression does not work in object list

Tags: c#, list, object, lambda, generic-list

I have an object list and I can add record with that sentence:

```
List<DragerClass.Alarm> alarms = new List<DragerClass.Alarm>();
public void createAlarm(int i, int[] alarms)
{
    alarms.Add(new DragerClass.Alarm(i, DateTime.Now, DragerClass.Dedector.Dedector_Name[i] + " UNDER RANGE"))`;
}
```

But when I try to remove an item, it behaves like lambda expression doesn't support:

```
public void removeAlarm(int i)
{
    alarms.Remove(x => x.Dedector_No == i);
}
```

I see that message when I stand on the code

> cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'Drager_GasDedection.DragerClass.Alarm' because it is not a delegate
>   type

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I also added `System.Data.Entity` in references. But still same. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ASh I tried that with RemoveAll now and the message is this now " 'Drager_GasDedection.DragerClass.Alarm' does not contain a definition for 'Dedector_No' and no extension method 'Dedector_No' accepting a first argument of type 'Drager_GasDedection.DragerClass.Alarm' could be found (are you missing a using...)

Comment: I think you need `alarms.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: "i" is the number of item not the index of list so RemoveAt is not helpful @MikeDebela

Comment: What do u mean *the number of item*?

Comment: @CanESER, i think you should explain *what* you are deleting (alarms or detectors) and describe your data structures. but using of `Remove` with predicate is incorrect

Comment: @ASh when i detect an issue on a dedector i put them in an object list on the code and i show the latest on main page, then if its ok i need to deltete that dedector from that list and i use the number of dedector to delete it, the i variable is the number of dedector. and from that dedector number i need to find the added object in the list and delete. maybe my proble is like u said, im using it incorrect can u help about it please

Comment: `alarms.RemoveAll(x => x.Dedector_No == i);`

Comment: @MikeDebela actually im using like that i wrongly put here single '='

Comment: @CanESER Not `Remove` it's `RemoveAll`. `Remove` expects `Alarm` object.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [methods of `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The method [`Remove(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) simply expects one element. If it is found in the list it is removed, otherwise nothing is done. `Remove` is not looking for a `Predicate<T>` that it will check.

[`RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) however expects a predicate. So you need to call:

```
alarms.RemoveAll(x => x.Dedector_No == i);
```

You also have to change `=` to `==` in your code since otherwise you are performing an assignment instead of an equality check. Furthermore note that the method will remove **all** alarms with the given detector number, not just the first.

Comment: In that list each dedector can max have one alarm so remove all is not problem and sorry for '=' it was actually what i wanted to type, im fixing now